# copying three different array to one array

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

I have three array..say array1,array2,array3. All these arrays contains dictionary.Now, I want to copy all the objects of these array into a single array and display in table view.
My problem is that how will I copy those three array into 1.
Say;

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:Dict1];
    NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:Dict2];
    NSMutableArray *array3 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:Dict3];
```

Now, I want to copy the contains of array1, array2, array3 into array4.How will I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
NSMutableArray *array4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array4 addObjectsFromArray:array1];
[array4 addObjectsFromArray:array2];
[array4 addObjectsFromArray:array3];

//Do something on array4

[array4 release];
```

Comment: Yes, u r r8..This has worked I just got this after posting Question

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *allObjs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: array1];
[allObjs addObjectsFromArray: array2];
[allObjs addObjectsFromArray: array3];
```

Comment: Yes, u r r8..This has worked I just got this after posting Question

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *array4 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [array1 count]; i++)
{
    [array4 addObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
for (int i = 0; i < [array2 count]; i++)
{
    [array4 addObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]];
}
for (int i = 0; i < [array3 count]; i++)
{
    [array4 addObject:[array3 objectAtIndex:i]];
}

//use your array4

 [array4 release];
```

Comment: Yours is true if he does have multiple objects in each of array1 2 and 3.  :-)

Comment: of corse, I think that the three arrays with 1 object in each one, is juste an example

Answer (score -1):

```
NSMutableArray * array4 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[array1 objectAtIndex:0], [array2 objectAtIndex:0], [array3 objectAtIndex:0]];
```

Comment: That will only put the first object from array1-3 into array4.

Comment: I might also add, that if his code example is his true code, that this way is actually the MOST SECURE way of writing it also!!!